# Laravel 5.0 page load in not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-5.5

I am learning the Laravel 5.0 from Laracasts. As per in third video .

I appended the WelcomeController.php with

```
public function contact()
    {
        return "Hello World asdasdasd";
        //return view('welcome');
    }
```

In routes.php I added this line as well

```
Route::get('contact', 'WelcomeController@contact');
```

But when I load the

```
http://localhost/myproject/public/contact/
```

**404 Page not found error is coming.**

**Edit:** 
Edited my document root to ~/public/ and still the contact page is not loading.

`http://myproject` displays the welcome page but 
`http://myproject/contact` 
says **404 Not Found {The requested URL /contact/ was not found on this server.}**

Comment: What does show `http://localhost/myproject/public`?

Comment: it works fine as default in server.php is require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';  output its same as http://localhost/myproject/public/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Normaly you would call the file without `/public` like

```
http://localhost/myproject/contact/
```

Comment: No., its not working, do I need to make some change in config files

Comment: The document root inside your servers config needs to target `path/to/yourApp/public`

Comment: wamp/www/myproject/server.php I have
$uri = urldecode(
 parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
); what part to edit